# Modify namespace of importing script in Python

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import, python-module

I'd like a function in my module to be able to access and change the local namespace of the script that's importing it. This would enable functions like this:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.set_a_to_three()
>>> a
3
>>>
```

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: What about just `a = 3`?

Comment: It's just a dumb example. I'll be doing more complex stuff that needs to come from `foo` and be assigned from `foo`. I know how Python assignment works normally, though.

Comment: Not possible, no. You could make a function change the globals, but it can only access the globals of the module it is defined in, not the one its running from.

Comment: @LukeTaylor oh sorry. I was confused because you seemed to have a good grasp on python. I'm not sure then.

Comment: @poke What about walking up the stack with `inspect`? I think it's possible there, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Accessing the stack frames is an implementation detail though and may not necessarily work in other Python implementations. Also, this still requires you to define `a` *before* you call the function, otherwise your script will not even compile because of a NameError.

Comment: @poke Thanks for the more detailed implementation.

Comment: I think `sys.modules[script_name].a = 3` should work? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @vaultah I think I'm trying to go the other way

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "local"? `locals() is globals()` is True on module level. Or do you want to be able to run `set_a_to_three` in functions/other namespaces?

Comment: @vaultah I'd like it to work on `locals()` ideally, just as the normal behavior of `a = 3` would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer was generously provided by [@omz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573626/omz) in a Slack team:

```
import inspect
def set_a_to_three():
    f = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    f.f_globals['a'] = 3
```

This provides the advantage over the `__main__` solution that it works in multiple levels of imports, for example if `a` imports `b` which imports my module, `foo`, `foo` can modify `b`'s globals, not just `a`'s (I think)

However, if I understand correctly, modifying the local namespace is more complicated. As someone else pointed out:

> It breaks when you call that function from within another function. Then the next namespace up the stack is a fake dict of locals, which you cannot write to. Well, you can, but writes are ignored.

If there's a more reliable solution, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To let the module access your script's namespace, you will have to pass the namespace to the function. For example:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.set_a_to_three(globals(), locals())
>>> a
3
```

The inside of the code would look like this:

```
def set_a_to_three(globalDict, localDict):
    localDict['a'] = 3
```

Sidenote: In this case, the globals dictionary is not needed but in cases where you need to modify global variable, you will need to use the globals dictionary. I have included it here for this reason to make the function extensible.

However, it would be easier to just set `a = 3` as Eli Sadoff said. It isn't a good practice to pass namespaces to other programs.

Comment: This is a decent answer in many cases. My situation is *slightly* more complicated because I'm already thoroughly abusing the Python language by replacing `sys.modules[__name__` with a custom class implementing `__getattr__`, meaning my functions aren't being called directly. Thanks a lot, this is a good option in a lot of cases, as it is for most users.

Comment: The view returned from [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) shouldn’t be modified.

Comment: Modifying locals is unsupported.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm... I've heard that, but the code I have given still works. Why?

Comment: In the current implementation, modifying locals only works at class or module scope, but not inside a function.

Comment: @user2357112 This code works in 3.5, and that is the most current. Are you referring to 3.5.2?

Comment: Try calling `set_a_to_three` from within a function.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: This solution can only modify global variables, so it's not perfect. See [Is it good practice to use `import __main__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023601/is-it-good-practice-to-use-import-main) for pros and cons.

In foo.py:

```
import __main__

def set_a_to_three():
    __main__.a = 3
```

[`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) is a name given to the current top-level program. For example, if you import `foo` from a module `bar`, then `bar` can be referenced with the name `__main__`. If you import `foo` from `bar`, which was initially imported from a module `qux`, then `qux` is `__main__`, etc.

```
bar -> foo
bar is __main__

qux -> bar -> foo
qux is __main__
```

If you actually want to modify variables in `bar` rather than `qux`, for example because `qux` contains unit tests, you can use something like this:

```
import sys
import __main__
if "bar" in sys.modules:
    __main__ = sys.modules["bar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to set in the `__main__`, because we know it's name.

```
#foo.py
import sys

def set_a_to_three():
    sys.modules['__main__'].a = 3
```

Comment: Could this be done with a  `setattr` if I didn't know its name?

Comment: I said the module's name.

Comment: Right. My bad. Sorry ;)