# Access global variable across multiple modules and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I have two python scripts which import each other and access a variable defined in the first script. But changes made to this variable are not seen in the other module.

Code with which the behavior can be reproduced:

File `a.py`

```
import time
import b

X = {}

def set():
    global X
    X[time.time()] = 1

def get():
    global X
    return X

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b.monitor()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        set()
```

File `b.py`:

```
import threading
import time

from a import get

def f():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print get(), 'in b'

def monitor():
    t = threading.Thread(target=f)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Run the program with `python a.py`. The result is:

```
{} in b
{} in b
{} in b
...
```

Expected output:

```
{"1518106774": 1} in b
{"1518106774": 1, "1518106775": 1} in b
{"1518106774": 1, "1518106775": 1, "1518106776": 1} in b
... // etc
```

... where the keys are `time.time()` strings.

I thought the global variable `X` should be able to be referenced wherever we want to. So why is `X` not updated in `b.f` even though the call to `set` is adding these keys to it?

Comment: Also `get()` never gets called. And if you want to change dictionary `X` in `set()` you have to have `global X` in it.

Comment: i ran the code as one file. I got the output as u expected except the first time [{} in b
{1518081548.076467: 1, 1518081549.077585: 1} in b
{1518081548.076467: 1, 1518081549.077585: 1, 1518081550.078685: 1} in b
{1518081548.076467: 1, 1518081549.077585: 1, 1518081550.078685: 1, 1518081551.079762: 1} in b
{1518081552.080953: 1, 1518081548.076467: 1, 1518081549.077585: 1, 1518081550.078685: 1, 1518081551.079762: 1} in b]

Comment: @shiva Put them into two files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that two instances of the variable X are created in such a set-up: one in `a.py` and another in `b.py`. The problem also occurs in this example that reduces it to the essence -- it is not related to creating threads:

### Problem in most simple form

File `a.py`:

```
X = "original value"
import b
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b.monitor()
    print ('A', X)
```

File `b.py`:

```
import a
def monitor():
    print ('B', a.X)
    a.X = "new value"
    print ('B', a.X)
```

When running `a.py` the output is:

> B original value
>   B new value
>   A original value

If the same `X` were accessed, then the last line of the output would have read:

> A new value

#### Explanation

This happens because `import` creates new instances of all global names therein. It will do this only upon the first time `import a` is encountered, and it really is the first time here. The module created by *execution* of `a.py` is named `__main__`, not `a`. Since this name is different from `a`, `import a` will really import the module, and not just reference the already loaded `__main__` module. See also the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) for a description of how module names are resolved.

As a consequence the names in these two modules are distinct; `import a` does not make the `__main__` names accessible to the other module.

#### Solution

A quick solution is to replace the `import a` statement in `b.py` with an `import __main__` statement, and use `__main__.X` as the qualified name you want to access in `b.py`. But this is not regarded the [advised way to proceed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24023850/5459839).

A more robust way is to ensure the global variables are not defined in the executed script, but in an imported module -- one that is imported by *both* `a.py` and `b.py`. The second `import` will make the names available that were defined when the first `import` was parsed:

File `common.py`:

```
X = "original value"
```

File `a.py`:

```
import common
import b
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b.monitor()
    print ('A', common.X)
```

File `b.py`:

```
import common
def monitor():
    print ('B', common.X)
    common.X = "new value"
    print ('B', common.X)
```

Now the output is:

> B original value
>   B new value
>   A new value

### Solution applied to your code

File `common.py`:

```
import time
X = {}
def set():
    global X
    X[time.time()] = 1

def get():
    global X
    return X
```

File `a.py`:

```
import common
import time
import b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b.monitor()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        common.set()
```

File `b.py`:

```
import common
import threading
import time

def f():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print common.get(), 'in b'

def monitor():
    t = threading.Thread(target=f)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Very helpful. But in term of the executed script part, by which you said it doesn't apply to the rules, where can I find any document or proof on that?

Comment: See update in the "Explanation" and "Solution" paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

## a.py

```
import time
import b

X = {}


def set():
    # global X
    X[time.time()] = 1


def get():
    global X
    return X


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b.monitor()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

## b.py

```
import threading
import time
import a


def f():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        a.set()
        print a.get(), 'in b'


def monitor():
    t = threading.Thread(target=f)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

## and finally here's your answer:

```
{1518083438.771415: 1} in b
{1518083438.771415: 1, 1518083439.772717: 1} in b
{1518083440.773916: 1, 1518083438.771415: 1, 1518083439.772717: 1} in b
```

Comment: Obviously this is not what I want. You just made the code correct, but didn't explain why the original version was wrong.

Comment: The most mysterious part of my original code is that, I was modifying the variable in a.py and reading it in b.py. However the sharing global variable was not correct.

Comment: because in f() of b.py has while loop which will never exit until we stop it and u mentioned set() in while loop which is below b.monitor() in a.py and it'll never go in to the while loop which is in a.py

Comment: while loop in f() of b.py will never terminate and it'll get blocked there itself and will never go to while loop of a.py. That's why it shown X= {} every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the fact that python does not truly allow global variables. A scope of a global is typically only in the same module. So when another module imports a module with globals, the namespace is copied and a variable is created with same original value. An imported Python module will not have direct access to the globals in the module which imports it, nor vice versa.

You may want to read the section 1.2.5 & 1.15.6 from  Norman Matloff's [Quick and Painless Python PDF Tutorial](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PLN/FastLanePython.pdf)