# Is "__main__" just a string literal?

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and one thing is bugging me is the exact type of `"__main__"`. So far, I have seen that `"__main__"` is mostly used as string literal like `__name__ == "__main__"`.
I mean, it is not a function, it is not a variable. With all the other built-in variables and functions starting with __ it is just confusing. Any special reason it has to start with __? I know it has special meaning in the context of modules and namespaces, but I am talking purely in the terms of basic/primitive data types.

Comment: Just to answer the question in the title: Yes, it's just a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `"__main__"` is a string literal, since module names are strings. The module is called `__main__` to distinguish it from modules named `main`, and since it is a system-assigned name.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's just a string. The fact that it has two underscores is because it's a "special name". Special names in Python have these two leading and trailing underscores.

What it actually represents is also explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html):

> ### 29.4. `__main__` — Top-level script environment
>
> `'__main__'` is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes. A module’s `__name__` is set equal to `'__main__'` when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.
>
> A module can discover whether or not it is running in the main scope by checking its own `__name__`, which allows a common idiom for conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or with `python -m` but not when it is imported:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>      # execute only if run as a script
>      main()
> ```
>
> For a package, the same effect can be achieved by including a `__main__.py` module, the contents of which will be executed when the module is run with `-m`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a string literal. Like magic methods like `__init__` start and end with 2 underscores in order not to be mixed with other methods,  `__main__` has such naming not to be mixed with names of existing files.

Comment: That may be nitpicking but `__main__` is in fact an existing module, just try `import __main__` :)

Comment: @MSeifert You are right, thanks :) Removed "modules" from my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, after importing `__main__` I can access existing variables using dot notation like `__main__.varname`. That clears a ton of confusion.

Comment: BTW, here is some discussion on ```import __main__```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023601/is-it-good-practice-to-use-import-main. There are several points on why such imports can be bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just a string literal that by design looks a bit like the names of some special methods in Python.

There is a bit more information in the docs: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are right `__main__` is a string literal.  `__name__` is just a variable (commonally called a dunder alias).

Here are two easy ways to prove this:

**Using `type()`:**

```
>>> type(__name__)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

This should be enough but you can also overwrite the value of `__name__` for example (you shouldn't however):

```
>>> __name__ = 'hello'
>>> __name__
'hello'
>>>
```

My answer [here expains what it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do/49637838#49637838).

> `__name__` is a DunderAlias - can be thought of as a global variable (accessible from modules) and works in a similar way to global.
>   It is a string (global as mentioned above) as indicated by `type(__name__)` (`yielding <class 'str'>`), and is an inbuilt standard for both Python 3 and Python 2 versions.