# No module named 'main'

Tags: python, module, package

Been getting this error

> > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
import main
import visuals
```

Anyone that could help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide with more details around `import main`? If there is a `main` named module in your working directory that you want to import. I intend to understand what you are trying to do here exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you meant to use `import __main__`... but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023601/is-it-good-practice-to-use-import-main) are some good reasons not to do that.