# Python: Problem with positional arguments required, when i import a textbox of a class from an external file into a function from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, import

I have problems when i try to import a textbox from another file's class. In the `x.py` file, i would like to import the textbox of the `Page1` class of the `page1.py` file.  The error occurs when you select the third checkbox and click the button. The problem is row of `x.py`: `if 5 >= folder.page1.Page1().textbox2`.

I show you my attempted solutions and the errors found:

- If in `x.py`, i write `if 5 >= folder.page1.Page1().textbox2`, i receive:

  `TypeError: Page1.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'master' and 'clicked'`
- If in `x.py`, i write `if 5 >= folder.page1.Page1(master, clicked).textbox2`, i receive:

  `NameError: name 'master' is not defined`

I show you a minimal reproducible example, composed of `main.py`, `page1.py` and `x.py` files. I couldn't reduce it more than this (for example the `def clicked` function is used to simulate the error).

I want to clarify that I need the condition to remain within the def Button3_func function; I need the lambda to remain; I need to use (as per my code) separate x.py and page.py files

How can I solve it? Can you show me an example solution please?

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from folder.page1 import Page1
from folder.x import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('480x320')

datalist = []
def clicked(flag, func):
    if flag:
        # append set to the list
        datalist.append(func())
    else:
        # remove set from the list
        datalist.remove(func())


notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.place(x=0, y=70)
f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='white', width=492, height=905)
page1 = Page1(notebook, clicked)
notebook.add(f1, text='Tab 1', compound='left')
notebook.add(page1, text='Tab 2', compound='left')

def try_print():
    # check that there is something in the list
    if len(datalist) > 0:
        c = set.intersection(*datalist)      
        print(c)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Print", command=try_print)
button.place(x=1, y=1)

root.mainloop()
```

**page1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from folder.x import *

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, clicked, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.textbox1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox1.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.textbox2 = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox2.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Checkbutton2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Checkbutton3 = tk.IntVar()



        #CHECKBOX
        Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = self.Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                                bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
        Button1.place(x=10, y=36)

        Button2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = self.Checkbutton2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                                bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton2.get(), Button2_func))
        Button2.place(x=10, y=66)

        Button3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checkbox 3", variable = self.Checkbutton3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                                bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), Button3_func))
        Button3.place(x=10, y=96)
```

**x.py**

```
import folder.page1
from folder.page1 import *

#CHECKBOX'S FUNCTIONS
def Button1_func():
    # put these in a set
    test1 = set(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
    return test1

def Button2_func():
    test2 = set(["a", "b", "c"])
    return test2

def Button3_func():
    test3 = set(["a", "b"])

    if 5 >= folder.page1.Page1().textbox2:
        print("Ok")

    return test3
```

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a circular import error, since in `page1.py` you're importing from `folder.x`, which I assume is `x.py`, and then `page1` is getting imported from in the `x.py` module. `NameError: name 'master' is not defined ` makes sense because you haven't defined `master` anywhere, and `TypeError: Page1.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'master' and 'clicked'` also makes sense since those are required arguments.

Comment: @Zev Averbach  I know this too, but I don't know how to fix it. So you ask yourself: what is the solution? How to fix? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create new instance of `Page1` inside `Button3_func()`.  You should import the already created instance `page1` in `main.py`.

Below is the modified `x.py` with updated `Button3_func()`:

```py
#CHECKBOX'S FUNCTIONS
def Button1_func():
    # put these in a set
    test1 = set(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
    return test1

def Button2_func():
    test2 = set(["a", "b", "c"])
    return test2

def Button3_func():
    # import page1 created in main.py
    from __main__ import page1
    
    test3 = set(["a", "b"])

    # better to cater invalid input
    try:
        if 5 >= int(page1.textbox2.get()):
            print("Ok")
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)

    return test3
```

---

Another suggestion is passing the instance `page1` to `Button3_func()`:

##### page1.py:

```py
from functools import partial
...

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, clicked, **kw):
        ...
        Button3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checkbox 3", variable = self.Checkbutton3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                                bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                # pass self to Button3_func()
                                command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, self)))
        Button3.place(x=10, y=96)
```

##### x.py:

```py
...

def Button3_func(page1):
    test3 = set(["a", "b"])

    # better to cater invalid input
    try:
        if 5 >= int(page1.textbox2.get()):
            print("Ok")
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)

    return test3
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and clear answer. I read that you used from __main__ import page1. I had never seen an import like this. What is it about? I know that you should never import something from the main file (but do the opposite).

Comment: `__main__` is a built-in name for the *main* module which is `main.py` for your case.

Comment: While this is nice and short I would not recommend it, since it for one obfuscates the origin of the variable and secondly will break your code if you have another entry point than your current `main.py` without the same `page1` object. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023601/is-it-good-practice-to-use-import-main)

Comment: @Jan_B So can you show us what you recommend for both of us? In your answer you show the solution with the x.py and page1.py files combined (which I didn't ask for). We are both curious to see your answer updated with what I asked in the question :)

Comment: I feel like a scratched record: Again, just read (only) the third paragraph! I am not discrediting @acw1668 answer. It does the trick and is nice and short. Just pointed out that it might not be good practice. I think he understands my answer perfectly as he has pointed out some flaws that I then corrected.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, I voted for your answer. For completeness, could you also show me a third solution with what the other user (with utmost respect towards him) was trying to show me please? He was kind, but he confused me, his ideas left me bitter and curious. I understand that I should write command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, int(self.textbox2.get()))) and then def Button3_func(textbox2) with if 5 >= self.textbox2, but self is underlined in red and doesn't work

Comment: because you do not need the `self` in that case for the comparison. Just use `if 5 >= textbox2`

Comment: @Horiatiki Since the argument of `Button3_func()` is `textbox2`, why do you use `self.textbox2` inside the function? Just use the argument name `textbox2`.  As I said in one of your deleted question, you have incorrect concept on Python programming and I suggested you to learn more on Python programming.

Comment: As @acw1668 said: learn more about OOP in python to understand `self` and instances etc.

Comment: @Jan_B if 5 >= textbox2 without .get?

Comment: in this case yes, since you already have the value passed. How about you join me in the [python chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to understand the basics of OOP instead of polluting the comments

Comment: @acw1668 I want to reread your answer better tomorrow, now I'm tired and I'm going to sleep. Thanks again, see you tomorrow

Comment: @Jan_B Thank you, you're so kind. I'm sorry you lost your temper earlier. However, with much serenity, it must be admitted that your answer was a little confusing :D (especially for those like me who are new to Python) Thanks for the chat idea. We'll create it tomorrow, now I'm going to sleep. Thank you for your time

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, everything works fine. Answer accepted :) I really liked your second solution. Thank you. But I was disappointed (not your fault) but because of my wrong idea. I believed that by taking the textbox value this way, instead of the sql query, I would solve the problem of that deleted question about closing and reopening the app in order to use the updated textbox values. I'm seeing if update_idletasks() and update() are right for me. What do you advise me? However I will open a new question in which I will explain better. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

**What's wrong with your code:**

Instance variables are only acessible if the respective class was instanciated. You try to instanciate `Page1` in `x.py` (by using the parantheses) but you do not need a new instance but want the textbox of the one you created in `page1.py`

**Combining `x.py` and `page1.py`:**

Normally I would recommend you to define the functions belonging to the buttons instantiated in `page1.py` in the same class as methods. This makes it easier to use the instance variables, because they don't have to be passed to the method:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, clicked, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.textbox = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Checkbutton2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Checkbutton3 = tk.IntVar()
        # CHECKBOX
        Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 1", variable=self.Checkbutton1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                 bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                 command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton1.get(), self.Button1_func))
        Button1.place(x=10, y=36)
        Button2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 2", variable=self.Checkbutton2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                 bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                 command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton2.get(), self.Button2_func))
        Button2.place(x=10, y=66)
        Button3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Checkbox 3", variable=self.Checkbutton3, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1,
                                 bg="#d9d9d9", foreground='black', activebackground="#d9d9d9",
                                 command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), self.Button3_func))
        Button3.place(x=10, y=96)

    # CHECKBOX'S FUNCTIONS
    def Button1_func(self):
        # put these in a set
        test1 = set(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
        return test1

    def Button2_func(self):
        test2 = set(["a", "b", "c"])
        return test2

    def Button3_func(self):
        test3 = set(["a", "b"])
        # get the value of the entry and cast it as integer to compare it to 5
        if 5 >= int(self.textbox.get()):
            print("Ok")
        return test3
```

Now you can reference the `textbox` directly through instance represented by `self`. But note that you have to `get()` the value of the entry and since it is a string also cast it to `int()`

**Keeping `x.py` and `page1.py` seperate files:**

If you insist on having the functions for the buttons in seperate files you have to pass the value of `textbox` to the function which compares it to 5. Do so by changing the command argument of your Button to: `command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, int(self.textbox1.get())))`.

Sice `Button3_func` is not directly called but passed to `clicked` as argument we have to use `functools.partial` to pass the function and the argument. Just import it on top of `page1.py` with `from functools import partial`.

Again: to pass the value as integer you have to `get()` it from `textbox1` and cast it as `int()` since it is string y default.

Now to the changes in `x.py`: ommit the import of `Page1` and instead change `Button3_func` to accept the argument we passed in the command of the button → `int_to_compare` (in this case the textbox1 value):

```py
def Button3_func(int_to_compare):
    test3 = set(["a", "b"])

    if 5 >= int_to_compare:
        print("Ok")

    return test3
```

This way the `Button3_func` stays very generic and can accept any integer value to compare.

If `Page1` has another entry `textbox2` you can simply change the command to: `command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, int(self.textbox2.get())))`

Comment: Could you show me an example solution please? (yes, my app is complex, better not create an App class like you said)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Please use my question code, because I'm new to Python and don't know how to solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: Your solution is not what I'm looking for. My code is an example with only one textbox, but I will definitely have to insert more textboxes. You compare with entry, but if I also have other textboxes, I don't think I will be able to use entry (being too generic). I will have to specify which textbox it is. Could you improve your code and show me how? Thank you

Comment: Could you show me in the solution please?

Comment: Note that the second argument of `clicked()` is a reference to a function, not the result of the function.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes i know. So what do you mean?

Comment: It means that the proposal `command=lambda what_to_compare=self.textbox: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), Button3_func(what_to_compare))` will pass the result of `Button3_func(...)` as the second argument of `click()` which will raise exception.

Comment: @Jan_B As you can see, I modified my code by adding self.textbox1 and self.textbox2. If I wanted to compare it to textbox1, I guess I would write def Button3_func(self.textbox1), then if 5 >= self.textbox1. I have a doubt about lamba. Should I write: command=lambda self.textbox1=self.textbox1: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), Button3_func(self.textbox1)))? The question is about your use of the text box

Comment: @acw1668 I'm confused. Are you saying that the code Jan_B suggests won't work?

Comment: @Jan_B Your constant changes confuse me and are of little use to me so far. Write many lines of theory, but write little demonstration code. Can you please show me the 2 types of solutions? (the one with entry and the one with get)? QUESTION: If I want to use textobox1, should I write this? command=lambda self.textbox1=self.textbox1: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, int(self.textbox1.get()))). I will be happy to accept your answer, but can you show me the demonstration code with self.textbox1, and with the two types of solutions? :)

Comment: In your last comment, you have used `self.textbox1.get()` directly when calling `clicked(...)`, so why bother using argument in the lambda?

Comment: @Jan_B In the code you wrote, it still says command=lambda what_to_compare=self.textbox. I'm interested in knowing exactly this part. I need to write command=lambda self.textbox1=self.textbox1: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), self.Button3_func)). I've asked you this several times, but you don't answer me. Note that in my code I use textbox1 and textbox2 (and not textbox)

Comment: Also you don't need the argument `what_to_compare` for the lambda in your updated `Page1` class.

Comment: @acw1668 Could I get an answer from an expert like you please? I'd like to see your solution. I will be happy to accept your reply in case of any help. Jan_B is kind, but he is driving me crazy and confusing: he changes and updates the answer so many times and doesn't explicitly answer what I ask him. He wrote a lot, but I didn't understand anything

Comment: @Jan_B You're showing me everything except what I asked for in the initial question. As I asked in my question, x.py and page1.py are separate files. I don't understand why you also added the code for the combination between x.py and page1.py to your already confusing answer. I don't need it and I didn't ask for it. I'm trying to try to understand your code (separate files), but it's not working. Can you show me this in your solution please?

Comment: Just read very carfully from top to bottom and ignoe the part for the copmbination which is just a kind suggestion for improvement. As the concept of lambda variables is to much for you and it is not really necessary I changed it again. Hope this is not to much to comprehend.

Comment: @Jan_B I see you updated your answer again. In one part you say to use command=lambda textbox1=self.textbox1: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, int(self.textbox1.get())))), while in another you say to use command=lambda: clicked(self.Checkbutton3.get(), partial(Button3_func, int(self.textbox2.get()))). They are written differently (apart from textbox1 or 2). Furthermore, I needed the solution with the separate files as per the question. Your current solution is of no use to me.

Comment: Again, just read the third paragraph, forget the previous comments! Transfer what you read into your code, then tell me what doesn't work. I am slowly losing my patience!

Comment: @Jan_B I'm losing patience too. Your many response edits and comments (often different from each other) have me confused. Just one question: in the version with x.py and page1.py, could you please show me what to use in x.py? I used if 5 >= int(self.textbox2.get()) and then wrote textbox2 in def Button3_func(textbox2), but self is underlined in red and gives me an error. Why? How to solve it?

Comment: Please for the love of god, just read the answer carefully: Ignore the second paragraph if you like it seperate. Take your code as it was at the point of your qestion and only change the command for the button like I wrote in the answer. then change the respective function to take one argument and compare to this argument alone. No need for a second `get()` if you passed an integer already!